# Link to div failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I have two pages: index.html and features.html. Buttons inside index.html link to specific divs in the features.html page like so:

```
<a href="features.html#category1">...</a>
```

Here's where the problem arised: Everything in features.html is jQuery-loaded through a JSON file, and all this loading is done inside a `$(document).ready()` function call. Even that div that I'm linking to above is created though the JavaScript. So for some reason, clicking those buttons in index.html always lands me at the top of features.html page. Now I'm not sure why this could be happening, but my best guess is that since that div is created only once all the HTML in the page has finished loading, the link doesn't know where to go before that.

So to overcome that issue, I tweaked my JavaScript to say so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //does all JSON parsing and creation of divs and other elements
    loadAll();

    //scroll to appropriate div
    var id = getAnchor();
    scrollToDiv(id);
});

function scrollToDiv(id) {
   window.scrollTo(0, document.getElementById(id).offsetTop); 
}

function getAnchor() {  
    var currUrl = document.URL;
    var parts   = currUrl.split('#');

    return (parts.length > 1) ? parts[1] : null;
}
```

All the JSON processing and creating those divs happens in the loadAll() function (which I have verified to work correctly). And a div with id "id" does eventually exist (checked in Chrome's "Element" while debugging).

But here lies the problem: document.getElementById(id) returns null. Which means that that div has not been created by the time I make the scrollToDiv() call. But how can this be? All the loading should have been completed in the loadAll() function! Debugging in Chrome shows the same thing.

What to do?

Thanks!

Comment: I am assuming your loadAll has asynchronous component to it.  if this is the case you might need loadall to execute a callback once its done. in this callback you would than include the call to scroll to div. Also, since you're using jQuery look into deferred.

Comment: `features.html#category1` means the page `feature.html` go to the Element with the HTML `name='category1'`. Your jQuery looks like it's repetitive, trying to accomplish the same thing. Also you are using `document.URL` then splitting it. You should use `location.hash.replace('#', '')` or `document.URL.replace('#', '')`. However, if you just want to click the link from one page and go to another pages HTML `name` attribute, you won't need that jQuery at all, unless you would like to apply a scroll effect, or something.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the content is still being loaded via the AJAX call while that code is running (hence getElement returning null).

I would suggest using a callback like [ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) on the request that calls `getAnchor` and `scrollToDiv` then you're guaranteed the content is there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As suggested, I used `$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {//scrolling code here});`. This kinda works but not perfectly. For a second, it takes me to the perfect Div, but then some more content from the json loads above/below and the screen shifts.

How can I get it so that the scrolling happens after not just all ajax requests complete, but also after all json parsing has completed?

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided the source code for loadAll(), but you mentioned that you load content over AJAX, and that is likely where the problem is. Remember that loading AJAX resources in Javascript is *asynchronous*, which means that a $.post(), $.get(), $.ajax() or XHR operation will not complete during the runtime of the call, but later once the resource has been received by the browser. Fun fact: it's typically impossible for AJAX calls to complete before flow continues beyond the origination point (the point in code where the request is started from), unless the sync option is used on the XMLHTTPRequest, which is a bad thing to do anyway in most circumstances.

What you should do is move the logic for scrolling to the anchor into a function which you should then call once all of your AJAX requests return and all the content has been set up. If you need to request multiple resources, you can keep a reference counter and fire the anchor scrolling function once all are accounted for.